# What is the null hypothesis?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

A person claims that he can differentiate if a medicine is working or a placebo. Therefore we test the null hypothesis $p=0.5$ and $\alpha=0.5$ with $n=50$ with a right handed hypothesis test.

Edit: The rest of the question says: how likely is a type ii error if the person can actually distinguish between working medicine and placebo by an accuracy of 70%.

The question is about : Does the person just guess or does the person really have the ability to distinguish between a placebo and working medicine.

How do I define the null hypothesis numerically ?

updated thoughts:

Since we have a right handed test, we try to see what upper area will lead us to deny a hypothesis.

H0 : The person can not distinguish between placebo and medicine

H1 : The person can distinguish between placebo and medicine

Comment: What's $p$ supposed to be, the probability that the decision is correct or the probability that the medicine works per patient?

Comment: I am not a hundred percent sure, that's why I posted the question. I edited the rest of the question above : I guess it might be about the accuracy of the medicine rather than the person's working accuracy. But I might misunderstand the question.

Comment: The problem is, what's the data? Is it data about cases in which the medicine worked or not, or data about cases in which the person correctly decided whether the medicine worked or not? The interpretation of the question is different in these two cases, and I can't tell which it is from the phrasing of the question.

Comment: Ok I got it now : It is about the accuracy of the person: Is the person able to distinguish between a placebo and working medicine or is the person just guessing.

Comment: This is the historical foundation of all of statistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea

Comment: @user762914 Yes - but why is there mentioned "Right handed test" which means that we deny the null hypothesis up from a certain outcome. I would assume testing both sides.

Comment: In informal terms, you "want to reject the null". Including the left-tail in your test is saying, "I am testing to see if she is either very good or very bad at detecting medicine". But you only want to see if she is very good, not both very good and very bad: if you rejected the null because she was so awful that multiplying her predictions by $-1$ was better than listening to her, that would not fit the hypothesis (or maybe it does, in some sense, but not in terms of the story). So you drop the left tail to make the test more demanding and consistent with the wordy story.

Comment: I'd accept this as an answer, if you want to post it. Thank you